# Get nth parent in DJANGO

Tags: django

I have models like this:

```
A->B->C->D
```

`B` is parent of `A`, `C` is parent of `B`...

I have `A` object from database. What is best way to get related `D` object from `A` object?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve an instance of `D` from an instance of `A`:

```
d_instance = a_instance.b.c.d
```

where `a_instance` is an instance of class `A`.

Whether it is the "best way" is another question; which depends on what you mean by "best". Performance-wise it depends on how your data is structured.

Remember that a join is effected each time another entity (or parent) is accessed using the dot notation shown above.